# Are SocketAsyncEventArgs supported in Unity 5.6.3p2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp, socketasynceventargs

I have created a networking api that I use in my applications. When compiling the unity project and running in the standalone windows player I receive the following exceptions which prevent my app from sending/receiving udp packets.

```
 NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.DoOperation 
(SocketAsyncOperation operation, System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket) [0x00000] 
in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFromAsync 
(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0 
  at DivergentNetwork.DnlUdpClient.BeginReceive () [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0 
  at DivergentNetwork.DnlUdpClient.Start () [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0 
  at UdpClient.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I am thinking it's something to do with standalone player however I can't figure out exactly what it is. I know this because I can run the app in Unity Editor successfully without errors.

If the SAEA class turns out to be unsupported with Unity then what would be the preferred alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Compatible Level to *.NET 2.0* .

Go *File* --> *Build Settings* then select your Platform. Click on the *Player Settings*. Go to *Other Settings* on the right. On the *API Compatible Level* drop-down menu, change it to *.NET 2.0* instead of *.NET 2.0 Subset*.

Comment: Well that fixed it! Could you explain why the player targets the 2.0 subset instead of just 2.0.

Comment: It offers reduced build size and speed start up time. That's why Unity used it as a default settings. They also did this because only few people use raw socket in their games in Unity. They expect most people to be using their network API so making a default settings that reduces app size and increases startup time makes sense in this case.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept answer if you issue is solved.